# Is this a valid proof? Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, cyclic-groups

I want to show that $(\mathbb{Q}^{+}, \cdot)$ is not cyclic.

Suppose that $0<q<1$ a generator for $(\mathbb{Q}^{+}, \cdot)$. Then, for every $a \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ there is a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$q^k=a$$

We know that $q^k$ is decreasing.

$$q^{k+1}<q^k$$

But, there is a number  c in $\mathbb{Q}^+$ such that

$$q^{k+1}<c<q^k$$

This means  that,

$$q^k \neq c$$ for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So, q cannot be a generator for  $(\mathbb{Q}^{+}, \cdot)$

The $q>1$ case is the same.

Is this right? , I would also like to see other forms of proof.

Thanks

Comment: After you write $q^{k+1}< c< q^k$, the argument must proceed this way : Since $q$ is a generator for $(\mathbb{Q}^+, .)$, there exists some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $c=q^m$. Thus $q^{k+1}< q^m< q^k$ implying $k+1< m < k$ which is not possible.

Comment: I felt that using the same 'k' and argument as I wrote was weak. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: The proof is clear and concise. I have a minor (optional) suggestion: rather than saying that the case for $q > 1$ is similar, you could instead point out that $q$ is a generator iff $q^{-1}$ is a generator. Also, strictly speaking, you did not mention the case $q = 1$.

Comment: This argument is more elegant; I liked it. And indeed, I forgot about the case q=1; it is trivial, but worth mentioning. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I think it's clearer to just choose a rational number $c$ between $q$ and $1$ directly (no need for $q^k$).

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Comment: I understand the importance of having rules in the forum to maintain a pleasant environment, but you guys go too far. It's never enough. I post a question explaining my doubt, with my steps, something is missing, I post another question about definitions and results, and they say there was a 'lack of commitment to studying.' It's too bureaucratic, it seems!

Comment: The doubt doesn't exist at a specific point; the doubt is throughout the entire demonstration. I don't even know if the approach is valid. I don't understand the need to make it clear that the doubt is throughout the entire demonstration.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be the following. Suppose that $a/b$ is a generator for $(\mathbb Q^+,\cdot)$, where $a,b\in\mathbb N$. We consider a prime $p$ which does not divide neither $a$ nor $b$. Then it must exist some $k\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ such that
$$(a/b)^k=p,$$
but this implies that $a^k=pb^k$. Hence $a^{|k|}=pb^{|k|}$ or $pa^{|k|}=b^{|k|}$, depending on the sign of $k$.
As a consequence, $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Very clean solution! Thanks.

Comment: But $(a/b)^0 = 1$... your proof shows that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not cyclic of finite order.

Comment: @AlexKruckman You're right, thank you! I've fixed the mistake. Can you explain what do you mean when saying that I show that $\mathbb Q$ is not a cyclic of **finite** order?

Comment: Your precious proof showed that there is no $k>0$ such that $(a/b)^k=1$, and therefore $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a finite cyclic group (since in a finite cyclic group, some positive power of the generator is $1$).